# Group by priority

Tags: mysql

I have this

```
+---------+--------+-------+
| article | name   |status |
+---------+--------+-------+
|    0001 | A      | enable|
|    0002 | A      | temp  |
|    0003 | B      | enable|
|    0004 | C      | enable|
+---------+--------+-------+
```

I want to select all from this table 'product' but I want to group by name and if there is a status **temp** I want to ignore the **enable** status and display only the product with the **temp** status

This result after query will be :

```
+---------+--------+-------+
| article | name   |status |
+---------+--------+-------+
|    0002 | A      | temp  |
|    0003 | B      | enable|
|    0004 | C      | enable|
+---------+--------+-------+
```

Could you help me to build this query ?

Comment: What if an article has only a `temp`???

Comment: you are saying that you need only the temp status value then why you are displaying the enable status also.

Comment: @RavinderReddy in my case an article can't be only temp

Comment: Can be some temp status for the same name? Do you want to see all them or just one?

Comment: @John i'm Assuming that so will be fastr with proper indexes : `select * from table1 where status = 'temp' 
union
select * from table1 where name not in (select distinct name from table1 where status = 'temp' )`

Comment: @Splash58 Oh yes this is an nice query too and this is faster :). Thanks a lot, could you edit your answer with this query ?

Comment: I've updated the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If find at least one temp in group, show it. Else show enable

```
select article, name, if(sum(status='temp'), 'temp', 'enable') 
    from  thetable
  group by name
```

To get article corresponding  to temp status, use such query

```
select * from table1 
   where status = 'temp' 
union 
select * from table1 
   where name not in (select distinct name from table1 where status = 'temp' )
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I need to display the data of the temp status. With your query it's impossible to get them

Comment: what is *data of the temp status* ?

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: If I have 3 states (enabled, disabled, temp) I want to ignore the disabled state in your query. If I add at the end of the query this it's ok ? : `and name not in (select distinct name from table1 where status = 'disabled' )`

Comment: In your query `temp` match the second select, Say `and status <> 'disabled'` after close bracket to not match temp and disabled

Comment: If I add this to the second query where status = 'temp'  and status = 'disabled' the query doesn't work :/ it returns me all line temp disable and enable

Comment: @John i think that i was wrong. The correct second `where name not in (select distinct name from table1 where status in ('temp', 'disabled'`))` If you want to exclude name with status = disable from the result

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try that too but your previous answer works too

Comment: I can't test now. I have some doubt about the previous. But, if it works, it good

Comment: I can't test now too. I'll try your second query tomorrow

Comment: I tried your second query but this doesn't work. But the first yes

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0974b1/1 - we remove from 2nd subquery all name having temp or disabl.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113995/discussion-between-john-and-splash58).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope help for you;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58d7bb/15)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`article` int, `name` varchar(1), `status` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`article`, `name`, `status`)
VALUES
    (0001, 'A', 'enable'),
    (0002, 'A', 'temp'),
    (0003, 'B', 'enable'),
    (0004, 'C', 'enable')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select  t1.*
from table1 t1
inner join (
  select count(distinct status) cnt, name, group_concat(status) as names from table1 group by name
) t2 on t1.name = t2.name
and (t2.cnt = 1 or (find_in_set('temp', names) > 0 and t1.status = 'temp'))
group by t1.name, t1.status
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58d7bb/15/0)**:

```
| article | name | status |
|---------|------|--------|
|       2 |    A |   temp |
|       3 |    B | enable |
|       4 |    C | enable |
```

Comment: Wow amazing this is a pretty query :D. Thanks a lot you saved me.